# Using Crypt library in salesforce

Tags: crypto

I want the equivalent apex code for below PHP:

```
crypt($timestamp.$username.$email,$secret_salt)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `crypt` function in PHP defaults to using DES, which is not supported in salesforce. For this reason you won't be able to use the method directly.

There are additional parameters in PHP that will allow you to use `crypt` with something other than the DES algorithm. Some of the [options supported by crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) that will work with salesforce are:

- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-256
- SHA-512

You could then use the [Crypto](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) class in Apex to do the hashing. If you have the option to choose any of these algorithms, I would recomend using SHA-256 or SHA-512.

One potential gotcha for your implementation is that you'll want to make sure the number of rounds and salt you are using matches on both the PHP and Apex side.

Answer (score -1):

Well, no idea what that PHP crypt method does but this is the Crypto class in Salesforce which might enable you to do what you want:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

Comment: Thanks Florian, I am aware of this class. I tried couple of methods in this class but they are not working. I want to call PHP web service in which I have to pass this token.